# How to convert Arabic subtitles to utf8 the right way?

Tags: command-line, software-recommendation, video, perl, encoding

Most DVD burners (if not all) ask for subtitles to be encoded in utf8, sure that's easy

```
for file in *.srt; do
◀ iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8 -o "$file".utf "$file" && mv "$file".utf "$file"
◀ done
```

That's what but now arabic subtitles are  anything but arabic, not all of them are in `ISO-8859`, they are either `ISO-8859-6` and some `Arabic windows CP1256` (I don't what is the encoding of each file, it's either this or that, can't check them all one by one, it will take a lifetime)

How can I convert them to utf8 while still having readable subtitles, i saw few software for windows claiming they can do that. What about Linux, I don't really care if it's a software or a bash script

Comment: Take a look at suggested ways of autodetecting file encoding https://superuser.com/questions/301552/how-to-auto-detect-text-file-encoding

Comment: @AndrzejA.Filip okay lets say i detect the encoding, how to convert it to utf8 without messing up the subtitles

Answer (score 1):

Use classic unix/linux way and combine a few simple tools together e.g.

```
#!/bin/sh    
ls *.srt | while read file ; do
  charset=`file -bi $file | sed 's/.*charset=//'`
  echo '###' $file $charset
  case "$charset" in
     us-ascii) charset="";; # no conversion needed
     utf-8)    charset="";; # no conversion needed
     binary)   charset="";; # no charset detected
     *) ;;
  esac 
  if [ "$charset" != "" ] ; then
    iconv -f "$charset" -t UTF-8 -o "$file".utf "$file" && mv "$file".utf "$file"
  fi
done
```

DO test first autodetection correctness without `iconv` line.
I suggest using `case` to limit conversion to a few explicitly listed charsets.

Alternative ways of charset autodetection are provided at
https://superuser.com/questions/301552/how-to-auto-detect-text-file-encoding

Comment: maybe im doing it wrong but when i type `done` it expects me to continue writing the script, it's not exiting the loop

Comment: What is reported by `sh -vx script_name`?

Comment: here http://justpaste.it/gnlq  and I think on line 2 you meant `ls *.srt`

Comment: I have fixed bug in passing parameters to iconv

Comment: but now the letters are not arabic http://i.imgur.com/yh14WXT.png not even close, more of greek :)

Comment: Could you check if `file -bi file_name` correctly recognizes arabic charset(s)?

Comment: it says `text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1` but that's wrong, the correct encoding for that file is `Windows cp 1256` maybe that's why I'm having troubles. in fact none of my files are encoded in `iso-8859-1`. Some of them are `iso-8859-6`

Comment: here's the file https://www.sendspace.com/file/2hbaye it's arabic subtitles for 24, season 9 episode 3

Comment: can I explicitly tell the script to convert from Windows1256 to utf8? I think automatic detection is not detecting that the encoding is windows1256, it thinks it's an iso. so i don't want automatic detection